# SQL Server Strange Characters from PHP but not Manual Query

Tags: php, sql-server

I have php code to update data to sql server using below statement

```
UPDATE [table] SET [third]='Several times (2–5x)' WHERE ...
```

However the updated data in sql server shows strange characters `Several times (2â€“5x)`, but if I tried to execute the SQL statement in Management Studio, it doesn't give me strange characters.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE [table] SET [third]='Several times (2–5x)' WHERE ..."
$sql_update_user_result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an encoding problem to me.

Try querying "SET NAMES utf8" before executing the update query.

```
odbc_exec($connection, "SET NAMES utf8");

$sql = "UPDATE [table] SET [third]='Several times (2–5x)' WHERE ..."
$sql_update_user_result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
```

Comment: iSWORD, I am not sure why the SET NAMES is not working to my Insert statement :(

Comment: Just figured it out, actually it gives me this error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'NAMES' is not a recognized SET option. .. I am not sure why it worked before..

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen in 2–5x is not the ascii minus but another similar looking puncuation mark (u+2013).
Just delete the – and type -.